# MBAir wifi hardware not installed

Tags: macos, wifi, hardware, macbook-pro

I posted this question over at the Apple Support forums a couple days ago, but I haven't gotten an answer yet so I'll also post it here.

Ever since I bought my 11' mid-2011 MBA I have issues with wifi. When the computer awakens from sleep, wifi gets turned off and can't be activated again. If I reboot, the wifi icon is greyed out and says "Wifi hardware not installed". The only way to fix it is by turning off and then powering on the MBA.

I've tried various fixes to no avail. I took a screen capture of the messages and also saved system reports of the three stages in this issue: wifi ok, wifi can't be activated and wifi not installed.

Can anyone help me?

http://d.pr/LZGb → system reports

http://d.pr/cng4 → screen capture

Thanks.

Comment: Take to an Apple Store (not an authorized Apple service centre) and talk to a Genius on hand. You could create a new account to test if it's something in your user profile, or completely reinstall Lion before you do to rule out software, but I'd bring it in as is, and let them perform diagnostics. To me, this has all the signs of a hardware issue (and may require a new logicboard) rather than a bug or erroneous preference file.

Comment: Agreed with cksum. Sounds like a faulty board to me. Take it to an apple store.

Comment: Unfortunately, I live in Chile, where there are no Apple Stores! I'll have to mail it to an authorized Apple service center in Santiago, the capital. Thank you for your kind advice!

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same problem on the same hardware, my solution (which has ben working OK for 3 days now) was to replace the DNS server settings with Primary, Secondary & Tertiary number strings determined by running an app called namebench.